# How to put objects dynamically in res.render

Tags: node.js, express

How can I get an object dynamically in res.render in express in a MEAN stack?

```
res.render('myTemplate', {title: 'This is my title'});
```

I want something like this:

```
res.render('myTemplate', function(){
    var myReturnObject{title: 'This is my title'};
    //do someting to generate return object;
    return myReturnObject;
});
```

Can anyone advise how can I generate my template variables programmatically in render function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data into an object and then pass it in the res.render.

```
var myReturnObject = {title: 'This is my title'};
res.render('myTemplate', myReturnObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `res.render()` calls will live in the context of a controller. For example , it could be something like (`app.get('/', function(req, res) {});`. Typically, you would want to fetch some data, then pass the fetched data to the template in your `res.render()` callback. The snippet below show how you would do this with a fictitious `callToDb()` function that query a database:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  callToDB(function(err, results) {
    const templateVars = {//use results like you want here};
    res.render('path/to/template/, templateVars);
  });
});
```